# Error running akka-http-microservice Activator template

Tags: akka-http

Error running `akka-http-microservice Activator template`
Unable to run example template:  akka-http-microservice from the Activator

Project builds, but on running, unable to access URL,

```
http://localhost:9000/ip/8.8.8.8
```

getting

> 'Internal Server Error'
>
> Error on running service:  [ERROR] [04/21/2016 12:06:35.506]
>   [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-10]
>   [akka://default/user/StreamSupervisor-0/flow-2-0-unknown-operation]
>   Error in stage [One2OneBidi]: Inner stream finished before inputs
>   completed. Outputs might have been truncated.
>   (akka.http.impl.util.One2OneBidiFlow$OutputTruncationException$)

This is just with code taken directly from downloaded template `*.zip` file.

Running on `Mac OSx, El Capitan.`  Running Scala v2.10.3.
Activator v1.3.9

============
(update)  still a problem after attempted fix from tutorials support team:

[DEBUG] [04/22/2016 11:58:47.749] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://default/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/2] Connection established to [freegeoip.net/104.131.63.168:80]
[ERROR] [04/22/2016 11:58:47.832] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://default/user/StreamSupervisor-0/flow-2-0-unknown-operation] Error in stage [One2OneBidi]: Inner stream finished before inputs completed. Outputs might have been truncated. (akka.http.impl.util.One2OneBidiFlow$OutputTruncationException$)
[ERROR] [04/22/2016 11:58:47.851] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(default)] Error during processing of request HttpRequest(HttpMethod(GET),http://localhost:9000/ip/8.8.8.8,List(Host: localhost:9000, C

Comment: I got a response from the company supporting the Activator template tutorials here; and they have fixed the transient issue:  https://github.com/theiterators/akka-http-microservice/issues/21

Comment: I retried running the built-service in the tutorial; and it looks like that didn't fix the problem.  This is now the full error trace on the Service side:

Comment: The full trace is included in my first 'answer' commentary below.

Answer (score 0):

I got a response from the company supporting the Activator template tutorials here; and they have fixed the transient issue:  https://github.com/theiterators/akka-http-microservice/issues/21

HOWEVER -- I tried running the Service again, and it looks like there's still a problem:

[DEBUG] [04/22/2016 11:58:47.749] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://default/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/2] Connection established to [freegeoip.net/104.131.63.168:80]
[ERROR] [04/22/2016 11:58:47.832] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://default/user/StreamSupervisor-0/flow-2-0-unknown-operation] Error in stage [One2OneBidi]: Inner stream finished before inputs completed. Outputs might have been truncated. (akka.http.impl.util.One2OneBidiFlow$OutputTruncationException$)
[ERROR] [04/22/2016 11:58:47.851] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(default)] Error during processing of request HttpRequest(HttpMethod(GET),http://localhost:9000/ip/8.8.8.8,List(Host: localhost:9000, C

Answer (score 0):

Most responsive help forums related to this issue are:

1) Activator templates 
https://github.com/theiterators/akka-http-microservice/issues

2) Akka Mailing List
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/akka-user

Answer (score 0):

Tried instead to download LATEST tutorial template; and overwrite the one I'd downloaded yesterday.  Then rebuilt, rerun that.

NOW the microservice comes up; and it appears to be working!  Problem resolved!